# What is the proper method of implementing onPause, onResume, surfaceCreated and surfaceDestroyed when developing a custom camera on Android?

Tags: java, android, camera, mediarecorder

I'm currently developing a custom camera application which takes a video using MediaRecorder for 5 seconds. I have implemented a number countdown overlay which counts down from 5.

My problem is that I am not 100% sure how to implement surface methods and pause/resume methods. If I close my app half way through recording and then open it again, the app freezes, shows a black screen, and eventually crashes.

Should onPause and surfaceDestroyed be used in unison? (Same question applies to onResume and surfaceCreated) How does surfaceChanged fit into this?

I'm guessing I need to find a way to restart my CameraActivity every time it resumes. (As I don't want it resuming half way through a countdown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at Activity lifecycle onPause and onResume for creating and destroying camera.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html#Pause